# How can I fix this search function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, search

The problem described concerns the `onSearch` function in a Flutter application using Firestore to retrieve and filter a list of users based on a search term entered by the user in a search field. Here's a detailed description of the problem:

1. **Objective**: The objective of the `onSearch` function is to filter the list of users based on a search term entered by the user in a search field. Filtered users should then be displayed on the screen.
2. **Issue**: When the search is performed, the list of filtered users contains no items, even though users matching the search term should be present. This indicates that the filtering is not working as expected, and users are not being correctly filtered based on the search.
3. **Analysis**: To identify the cause of the problem, several points need to be examined:

   - The correct construction of the Firestore query to filter users based on the search term.
   - The correct reception and conversion of the `QuerySnapshot` returned by Firestore.
   - The correct assignment of the `filteredUsers` list with the filtered users.
   - The update of the user interface to display the filtered users.

In summary, the described problem concerns the inability to correctly filter the list of users based on a search term, and it requires thorough analysis and modifications in the filtering process to be resolved.

Here's a description of what you tried and what you expected to happen:

**What you tried**:

1. You implemented the `onSearch` function in your Flutter application to filter a list of users based on a search term entered by the user.
2. You constructed a Firestore query within the `onSearch` function to filter users by their name, using `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `isLessThanOrEqualTo` conditions.
3. You listened to the snapshots returned by the Firestore query and updated the `filteredUsers` list accordingly.
4. You added debug print statements to monitor the `filteredUsers` list for any changes.

**What you expected to happen**:

1. When the user enters a search term, you expected the `onSearch` function to filter the list of users based on that term.
2. You expected the Firestore query to correctly filter users whose names contain the search term, regardless of case sensitivity.
3. You expected the `filteredUsers` list to be updated with the filtered users retrieved from Firestore.
4. You expected the user interface to reflect the updated `filteredUsers` list, displaying the filtered users accordingly.

```
void onSearch(String search) {
  // Convert the search term to lowercase and uppercase for case-insensitive matching
  String searchLower = search.toLowerCase();
  String searchUpper = search.toUpperCase();

  // Check if the search term is empty
  if (search.isEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      // If search term is empty, set filteredUsers to the entire list of users
      filteredUsers = List.from(users);
    });
    return;
  }

  // Perform Firestore query to filter users based on the search term
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchLower)
      .where("name", isLessThanOrEqualTo: '${searchUpper}z')
      .snapshots()
      .listen((QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    setState(() {
      // Convert the snapshot into a list of QueryDocumentSnapshot
      filteredUsers = snapshot.docs.cast<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>().toList();
    });

    // Debugging: Print the filtered users
    print("Filtered Users: $filteredUsers");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're doing a string search here:

```
String searchLower = search.toLowerCase();
String searchUpper = search.toUpperCase();
...
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Users")
    .where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: searchLower)
    .where("name", isLessThanOrEqualTo: '${searchUpper}z')
```

Since these are strings, the ordering is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) and in that order lowercase characters come **after** uppercase characters. For reference let's use this [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/):

[image]

If `search` is `a` or `A`, then your code searches for `name >= "a" AND name <= "A"` or in ASCII values `name >= 141 AND name <= 101`, which is always an empty result set.

If you swap the arguments, you will get results. But you'll probably get many more results, as there are lots of values between `"A"` and `"az"` that you probably don't want, such `"B"`, `"C"`, etc

---

In general, this is not a good way to implement case-indifferent search. The above performs a start **at**/end **at** operation.

If you want to search for results starting **with** `a` OR `A`, that'd be an [OR query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_14) like this:

```
.where(
    Filter.or(
      Filter.and(
        Filter("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "A"),
        Filter("name", isLessThanOrEqualTo: "A~"),
      ),
      Filter.and(
        Filter("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "a"),
        Filter("name", isLessThanOrEqualTo: "a~"),
      ),
    ));
)
```